# AppCompat ProgressBar coming blue in android L

Tags: android, material-design

I have customized my themes as per the documentation the action bar and the nav bar color is changing. But my progress dialog is still in blue. please help me sort this out:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_green_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/loader_dark_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_green_dark</item>

</style>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `ProgressDialog`? You'll note how the [material design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-behavior) greatly prefers inline progress rather than modal dialogs.

Comment: @ianhanniballake : what should i be using? I m new to this material design part

Comment: A `ProgressBar` directly in your layout is certainly a good place to start!